# Suppress "Methods inherited by base class" in subclass docstring

Tags: python, inheritance, ipython, docstring

I am subclassing a class with a large number of methods and long docstrings. If I call the IPython help function I see all the help of the original class.
I guess this is expected, is there a way to suppress this? I'd like to see only the methods I redefined.

`mymodule.py` is:

```
import matplotlib.axes
class MySubclass(matplotlib.axes.Axes):
    pass
```

If I do in IPython:

```
import mymodule
help(mymodule)
```

The printout is huge because it contains all of the "Methods inherited from matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes:" which is megabytes of text because it lists the docstrings of all the methods of the class.

Comment: Are you asking if your `MySubclass` class can suppress that output, or are you asking if there's a way to use the `help` function without seeing that output, or something else?

Comment: The first would be better, but even the second would be interesting

Comment: Even just some insight on this would be interesting, do you confirm this is expected? Is it a Python or IPython feature?

Comment: It's not an IPython feature; the `help` function is a builtin. And I don't think it's possible to suppress that output. Best you can do is probably to write your own `help` function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://github.com/healpy/healpy/issues/449), a possible working solution would be to remove the doc manually

```
## List the methods from the original class
method_list = [func for func in dir(mymodule.MySubclass) if \ 
  callable(getattr(mymodule.MySubclass, func))]

## Remove doc for methods
for func in method_list:
  ## Change only original user defined methods
  if ("_" not in el[0:2]):
    original_method = getattr(mymodule.MySubclass, func)
    setattr(original_method, "__doc__", "")
  else:
    pass
```

This could be easily encapsulated in a decorator, and called when instantiating the subclass or importing the module.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i can think of is that if you make all the functions defined in the base class in your child class and make your own docstrings inside them, then they can be overwritten. You can even leave blank docstrings, whatever you prefer, but it will be quite impractical though.